# divide image (document word or similar - image snapshot) into sections algorithm

Tags: algorithm, classification

Have you ever encountered such a problem?
I have only image copy of document and need divide into section: pictures, graphics, graphs, paragraphs maybe.

Is there anywhere library, algorithm or tool, which can do something like this or similar?

Comment: You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_layout_analysis

Comment: Thanks.
Do you know good library/ies dealing about it?

Comment: in the old days, people tended to read the pages you linked to. This seems to be over now.

Comment: Sorry, I read this article, but there are everything is vague. Thanks to you I know what i want to search :D and finally find what i need.

Comment: I ask about something more specific because i thought there are something like that exists. Any combination or something similar.